# Manage a Sharepoint Site with Microsoft Graph API using an Azure AD Entreprise Application

Tags: azure, sharepoint, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I created an entreprise application in Azure AD, that have the permission `Sites.ReadWrite.All` on Microsoft Graph API. When requesting Microsoft Graph API, I'm able to read and write data on public sites of my organization, **but not on the private ones** (ex: when requesting the URL: `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/xxxxxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx`, I get this message: `Requested site could not be found`).

I tried to add my enterprise application by entering its id in the "Add Members" panel on the Sharepoint site, but it was not found. How can I grant my Entreprise Application to make queries on private sites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the Sites.ReadWrite.All permission you can access and edit all sites in the tenancy, both public and private. Please double check your site id.

Try this endpoint to access the site,

```
'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{{ TENANT NAME }}.sharepoint.com:/sites/{{ SITE NAME }}:/'
```

Replace {{ TENANT NAME }} with your tenancy

Replace {{ SITE NAME }} with the name of the private site